# Countrow/selection limit/data column limit

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can I ask coding to limit the data selection in drop down list?

For example: in 1 drop down list have 3 selection, in every selection have limit 20 person can choose in every data.

```
<tr><td><label><font face='Verdana' size='3'><b>Kelab Persatuan</b></font><td>:   </td>
<td><select name="kelab_persatuan" id="kelab_persatuan">
    <option value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
    <option value="Bahasa Melayu">Bahasa Melayu</option>
    <option value="Bahasa Inggeris">Bahasa Inggeris</option>
    <option value="Rekacipta">Rekacipta</option>
    <option value="Agama Islam">Agama Islam</option>
    <option value="Pend.Alam Sekitar">Pend.Alam Sekitar</option>
    <option value="Seni dan Visual">Seni dan Visual</option>
    <option value="Muzik dan Budaya">Muzik dan Budaya</option>
    <option value="Komputer">Komputer</option>

</select></td></tr>
```

Comment: What _exactly_ is your problem? Provide some code please.

Answer (score 0):

I think what i understand from your question is that you need to limit the selectuion in a multiple select.

You can try your hands on jquery and the script could look like this.....

```
$("selectid").change(function () {
if($("selectid option:selected").length > 3) {
     //some thing like an alert saying no more selecting.
  }
 });
```

Now i am using the word selectid cause i use id as selector in jquery. It could be the name of your selectbox also..cheers..

Comment: I don't know where to put this coding.there my example coding